# How to make a long connection with http.Client?

Tags: http, go

I try to connect a http server as long connection, like below:

```
func main() {
    request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://long.connection.org:8080/", nil)
    request.SetBasicAuth("xxx", "oooo")

    http_client := &http.Client{}
    response, _ := http_client.Do(request)

    var buf []byte
    for {
        _, err := response.Body.Read(buf)
        if err == io.EOF { break }
        fmt.Printf("%s", string(buf))
    }
}
```

But read from response.Body always empty. And seems I can't use response.Body to send data to server.

Any one can help?

Comment: First thing to do : check errors. Why don't you look at the errors returned by http.NewRequest and http_client.Do ?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "io"
        "log"
        "net/http"
)

func main() {
        request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://www.example.com/", nil)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        http_client := &http.Client{}
        response, err := http_client.Do(request)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        buf := make([]byte, 4096) // any non zero value will do, try '1'.
        for {
                n, err := response.Body.Read(buf)
                if n == 0 && err != nil { // simplified
                        break
                }

                fmt.Printf("%s", buf[:n]) // no need to convert to string here
        }
        fmt.Println()
}
```

Edit: Added forgotten error handling of NewRequest.